# FancyBox shows content from href

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox-2

**Html**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>CountryName</td>
    <td>
      <div class="action">
         <a class="edit-country" href="/Edit-Country?countryId=1"></a>
         <a class="delete-country" href="/Delete-Country?countryId=1"></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$(".edit-country").fancybox({
     type: "inline",
     modal: true,
     closeBtn: false,
     helpers: {
            title: null
     }
});
```

I want that if i clicked on `Edit` it will be opened a popup with the content it gets by the `href`. But it takes me to another page.

It will open at same page if i use `type='ajax'` but it didn't initialize `document.ready` method of `Edit-Country` page.

Is there any way that it will be opened at the same page and also initialize `document.ready` method of `Edit-Country` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use a different page, you need set type as 'iframe'.
inline used when you want to show in popup window from inside page like div/panel

```
$(".edit-country").fancybox({
 type: "iframe",
 modal: true,
 closeBtn: false,
 helpers: {
        title: null
 }
});
```

http://fancybox.net/api